# use webpack with vue, but require seems not working

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I use webpack to bundle js, sample:

```
var Vue = require('vue')

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        info: { email: '' },
        email: ''
    },

    methods: {

        onSignin: function (e) { },
    }
})
```

use Webpack to generate a bundle and include it in html, got error:

```
test3b.js:7019 Uncaught TypeError: Vue is not a constructor(…)
```

any idea what missing here? thanks,

Comment: are you using single file components or not ?

Comment: just trying to put Vue into webpack instead of include it in the html,

Comment: answered your question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var Vue = require('vue')
```

is correct, but it pulls in the runtime version by default:

```
vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js
```

this will trigger an error and yet labeled as warning, 
need to tell webpack to pull in another version,

```
vue/dist/vue.min.js
```

to do that, add following into webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.min.js'
    }
}
```

this is [documented here](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/215), but just not easy to locate

Comment: thanks! adding the `resolve` to my webpack config fixed my problem!

Comment: it solved the issue for me. But do i always have to do that? I mean should i not use the runtime version of vue ever? I am new to JS and just trying to get my head around npm and webpack and staffs. So really confused here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout [vue-hackernews-2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0) project which provides a sample implementation of vue with webpack, in their [app.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/src/app.js), you will find following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

You must already be having `vue` dependency in `package.json`, as it is [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/package.json#L26) and you have installed it via: `npm install`

Comment: can we use Vue = require('vue') ?

Comment: @AngeloC Ideally I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work, does `import`  syntax works?

Comment: package has vue dependency: "dependencies": {
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.0-beta.25",
    "vue": "^2.2.2"
  }

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code below. You are not creating new variable, that's why you can't use: `var app = ...` . Just call new Vue.

Also, replace `require` with ES6 import `import Vue from 'vue'`

```
import Vue from 'vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        info: { email: '' },
        email: ''
    },

    methods: {

        onSignin: function (e) { },
    }
})
```

Similar as in official VueJS Webpack template. https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/src/main.js

Comment: use new Vue,  got the same error, samples found usually uses import instead of require, maybe that's the reason?

Comment: I edited the answer few minutes ago as I forgot about `import` . Edit is pending. 

Also, replace require with ES6 import import Vue from 'vue'

Comment: change it into 'import ..', I got a new error:test3b.js:636 [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build. 
(found in <Root>)

Comment: but it's working now ? Warn is not an err.
Are you sure you did not include your output file from Webpack and Vue itself ?

Comment: it was error in the console, the Vue source code is included in the output file

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bfrxnLyn/  the js part is the source, need to webpack it into test3b.js